# Easiest platform to scrape/store/display and search data?

Tags: database, web, scrape

I have plan to build a website where the users could enter some data about their own cars (say number of years, their self-rated maintained level and so on) and then I can scrape some of the manufacturer data from various manufacturer's/car review websites (like engine, auto/manual, etc), dump all these data into a database (I can do MS-SQL or MySQL), and then have a front end user form on the website that allows someone to search by any of the fields listed and then enter the price they think the car is worth.

Now, the issue is, I have good knowledge in SQL and HTML, and have used VB.NET to do some scraping tasks before, however I have little experience with PHP and other platforms. Therefore, I am just wondering what would be the most efficient way for me to get this done? Would PHP be a lot better than the .NET framework when used to scrape websites?

As this is my own pet project, I am flexible to use any version of any software I like (as long as it is not like Oracle where I can't afford to pay), the platform could be on Windows or Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about code efficiency, definitely go with machine code. If you're talking about programmer efficiency definitely use a platform you already know. Having said that, Python is a great language, which everyone should use for everything that isn't already done in C. ;-)

(And Django (in Python) is a lovely web-framework. It's *Don't-Repeat-Yourself* motto is in sharp contract to .Net's *Copy-Paste-Everything-Twice* workflow, at least in my experience.)